# On the fly razor compilation

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

cshtml files are stored in Views subfolder.
I want to store some views in database and i want to allow users to change them.

Is there a way to do that ? I need to compile on the fly but i don't know how.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/301/loading-asp-net-core-mvc-views-from-a-database-or-other-location

Comment: Thanks i have already read it. What i do not understand is where are stored compiled views in this case ?

Comment: They are not stored. You store the template ("cshtml"), they will be compiled at runtime. Don't forget to add `services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();` in `Startup.ConfigureServices(...)`

Comment: This is strange because in the case of a .cshtml file, everything is compiled into a dll... What i want to do is to also compile into bytecode what is stored in database

Comment: Ah ok, I get you now. But if you want the users to change them, they would add the bytecode to the DB? Why not the cshtml source? IMHO you can't do the "get bytecode as byte[]" with native Razor, but you could give the https://github.com/adoconnection/RazorEngineCore a try. I'm using this (with .Net Core 3.1) to compile LaTeX Templates to latex and then render a PDF.

Comment: User will change cshtml, but i need to compile. I will have 2 fields in the database: the cshtml and the bytecode

Comment: definitely look at RazorEngineCore, like I mentioned above (available via nuget). You can do: `IRazorEngineCompiledTemplate template = razorEngine.Compile("Hello @Model.Name");
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
template.SaveToStream(memoryStream);` then save the stream to the DB

Comment: Thanks a lot but how can i ask blazor to work with this binary template for this controller and this domain ? Thanks